# How to translate "I'm looking for opportunities to practice my French"?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

I'm looking for a roommate, and am hoping to find one who speaks French so that I can practice with them. I was thinking of including the following snippet in my ad.  Is this idiomatic?

> *Je parle français assez bien, mais je cherche toujours des occasions pour m'améliorer.  Donc, je serais bien content d'habiter avec un(e) francophone.*

I'm wondering in particular about the use of *m'améliorer*.  Is it clear that this refers to my french-speaking ability? Or would it be better to say something like “*je cherche toujours des occasions pour pratiquer*”?

Comment: Also, apart from the obvious “I want to get better” good reason to ask this question, I suggest not taking your ad too far from the french you're actually able to speak (e.g. don't make it a lot more idiomatic), or people will wonder why you try to get better (or you could well receive useless visits people fooled by the ad, in a way or the other).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Améliorer* est le bon mot ici. Je ne vois rien à redire à ta première phrase. Tu pourrais aussi dire « je cherche toujours des occasions pour pratiquer » (attention à l'orthographe, pas de C à *pratiquer*) : le sens est différent, mais ça revient au même.

La deuxième phrase me semble moins idiomatique. Elle est tout à fait compréhensible, mais ce n'est pas ce que je dirais spontanément. Je dirais plutôt « je serais heureux d'habiter avec un(e) francophone ». Vu que tu veux pouvoir bavarder avec ton collocataire, tu pourrais aussi dire quelque chose comme « Je cherche un(e) collocataire francophone avec qui pratiquer mon français ».

Comment: Histoire d'éviter l'embrouille masculin/féminin, je choisirais "Je cherche un(e) collocataire francophone avec **qui** pratiquer mon français".

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Bonne idée. Ça évite surtout ce subjonctif futur qui manque en français.

Comment: Je m'étais même pas rendu compte que j'avais zappé le "je pourrai", tout concentré que j'étais sur le "qui" :)

Answer (score 0):

Vous pourriez essayer cela :

J'aimerais partager ma chambre avec quelqu'un de langue française qui puisse m'aider avec ma connaissance encore limitée de la langue française. SVP adressez-vous ...